# Quarkus native executable & google-oauth-client

Tags: java, kotlin, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I've added a sample project [here](https://github.com/danielcamargoeti/quarkus-lambda) that replicates the issue.

My goal is to simply build a `GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl`. What is interesting about it is that a set of map entries that is fully "hydrated" running on JVM is empty when executing the native executable.

[image]

I've tried registering classes for reflection with no success. Here is an example (from the file `reflection-config.json`):

```json
[
    {
        "name": "com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl"
    }
]
```

Any thoughts?

My guess is that this has something to do with API's way of transporting data:

```java
public class GenericData extends AbstractMap<String, Object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it does have something to do with the way data is transported.

In the snippet below, you will notice that the `@Key` annotation is used to generate the actual key when hydrating the entry set.

```java
public final class Userinfo extends GenericJson {
    @Key
    private String email;
    @Key("family_name")
    private String familyName;
    ...
```

It turns out that this approach is widely used on libs that depend on `google-http-client`.

I am using Kotlin, so my solution was to do this:

```kotlin
@RegisterForReflection(
    targets = [
        // google-http-client
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders::class,
        com.google.api.client.json.rpc2.JsonRpcRequest::class,
        com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature::class,
        com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebToken.Header::class,
        // google-api-client
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.Details::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError.ErrorInfo::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError.Details::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError.ParameterViolations::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonErrorContainer::class,
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.mtls.ContextAwareMetadataJson::class,
        // google-api-services-oauth2-v2
        com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfo::class,
        com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Tokeninfo::class,
        com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2.Tokeninfo::class,
        com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2.Userinfo.Get::class,
        com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2.Userinfo.V2.Me::class,
        com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2.Userinfo.V2.Me.Get::class,
        // google-oauth-client
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthCallbackUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthCredentialsResponse::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationRequestUrl::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.PasswordTokenRequest::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.RefreshTokenRequest::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenErrorResponse::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken.Payload::class,
        com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenResponse::class
        // @TODO: This must be fixed first
        // https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/issues/947
        // com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenVerifier.PublicKeyLoader.JsonWebKeySet::class
        // com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenVerifier.PublicKeyLoader.JsonWebKey::class
    ]
)
class ReflectionConfig
```

I hope that will help someone else.